# How can I fix the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push)' during react test?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, ts-jest

Testing is in progress through react-testing-library. I'm implementing a test that moves to the main page when a button is clicked in the process of testing a component, but it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

i got this error
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')**

```
//Error.test.tsx

test('메인페이지로 이동하는가?', async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    render(
      <Router location={history}>
        <ErrorCompnent />
      </Router>,
    )
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    screen.getByTestId('goHome')
    await user.click(screen.getByTestId('goHome'))
    // expect(screen.getByTestId('main')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
```

```
//Error Component
<button
          data-testid="goHome"
          onClick={() => {
            navigate('/')
          }}
        >
          메인으로 이동
        </button>
...
```

```
//Main.tsx
<article className={styles.container}>
      <section data-testid="main" className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.column}>
          <Calculate />
          <PrivateInfo />
        </div>
      </section>
...
```

Comment: Where does the `navigate` function come from? Which version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: @slideshowp2 you're right. Currently, the above project is using react-router v6.